# execute shell commands inside a target in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefile. I'm trying to perform some shell operation inside a makefile under a target. I made a new_target without modifying the working code. The code looks like this:

```
all: new_target existing_target
    

new_target:
    TEST_FILES:=$(wildcard $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp)
    for f in $(TEST_FILES); do \
        $(shell ls) $$f; \
    done
```

Error:

```
TEST_FILES:=/docker_home/myhome/Test/b.cpp /docker_home/myhome/Test/file.cpp /docker_home/myhome/Test/a.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: TEST_FILES:=/docker_home/myhome/Test/b.cpp: not found
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'new_target' failed
make: *** [new_target] Error 127
```

The idea is to perform a shell operation(similar to `ls`) on all the `.cpp` files in a particular directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ...

> ```
> TEST_FILES:=$(wildcard $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp)
> ```

... is (GNU) `make` syntax that assigns a value to a *`make`* variable.  Your recipe instructs the shell to execute it as if it were a shell command.  Obviously, that doesn't work.

Additionally, `$(shell ls)` doesn't do what you intend.  It will run the `ls` command without arguments in `make`'s working directory, at the time the makefile is parsed, and insert the results into the command to be run.  If you want to run a shell command in your recipe then just put the command in the recipe.

The easiest solution would probably be to move that line outside the recipe (and dedent it):

```
TEST_FILES:=$(wildcard $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp)

new_target:
    for f in $(TEST_FILES); do \
        ls $$f; \
    done
```

Note that the `$(wildcard)` function will be evaluated and the results assigned to `TEST_FILES` at the time that the makefile is parsed, not when the `new_target` target is built, but that appears unlikely to be an issue in this case.

Of course, unless you need `TEST_FILES` for something else, too, a much cleaner way would be to merge it together and get rid of `wildcard`:

```
new_target:
    for f in $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp; do \
        ls $$f; \
    done
```

Or, best of all for this particular case:

```
new_target:
    ls $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it in below way as `TEST_FILES` is a make variable and you should not mix `make` and `shell`:

```
TEST_FILES:=$(wildcard $(HOME)/Test/*.cpp)
new_target:
    for f in $(TEST_FILES); do \
        ls $$f; \
    done
```

Note : 
When it is time to execute recipes to update a target by make , they are executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe, unless the .ONESHELL special target is in effect. So you dont require a `$(shell)` explicitly.